# How to deal with training models on data where the examples are highly dependent on each other?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, bounds

Say you have a dataset of products sold at a store with the special condition that each day there is only one of each product in stock.  That is, if there are multiple orders for a given product on a given day, only one would get filled and the rest would not get filled.  The goal is to predict whether an order placed today will be filled the next day.  The prediction must be made the day before (when it is ordered) so at prediction time you have no information about the next day.  You still have information about the past though and you can look at things like past fill-rate for a given product - i.e. you can see if a given product tends to get filled/not filled a lot. Assume you have no other information that would make the examples conditionally independent (e.g. knowing beforehand where a particular order is in priority for the next day).

My question is how to deal with the strong dependence between examples in the dataset.  Under this setup, an order for a given product would not get filled **because** another order of the same product did get filled.  In this way the examples strongly depend on each other.  Also, given this setup, all orders of the same product would need to have the same prediction (since they all possess the same information), yet, in the case of multiple orders of the same product on the same day, some of those predictions would necessarily be wrong.  In addition, at training time you would have many cases of training examples possessing the exact same information associated with different labels which would confuse the model.  It seems like this would mean that there would be an upper bound in the performance of any model you try to train because it would be impossible to predict everything correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is actually viable to try to predict that accurately, since the data points are highly random... there's no actual non-random correlation between the inputs and the outputs, is there?

Comment: @Johanna Yes that was what I was thinking although I think there would be a small signal - for example, some products might be less popular and have fewer orders and therefore more likely to get picked than popular ones.  That might at least allow for the model to learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would try a **Random Forest** model (bagged trees), since they have a strong predictive power and aren't too subjective to data noise and overfitting, and also they work with bootstrap aggregation, so the fact that they train each tree on random samples with substitution might help your case. But I believe you have quite a difficult problem at hands, because the probability of all the correlations between inputs and outputs being random is probably high.